# Facebook login popup close button event

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook login popup in my website. I am showing a loader for api response. But when user click on close button (X) of facebook login window, My loader is showing infinite. So i want to get that event when user click on close button. I am using below code for facebook login popup.

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '###',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.1'
  });

  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

  window.checkLoginState = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      document.getElementById('loader-response').classList.add('show');
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      getProfile();
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem('facebook',false);
    }
  }  
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code.

Just add `document.getElementById('loader-response').classList.add('show');` after the `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)` function.